# Error building angular+ngrx 8 for production when using createReducer function

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator, ngrx

Currently I am trying to build an Angular + NgRX 8 application with the new NgRX *creator* functions. But when I am building this for production, there appears the following error:

> Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'createReducer' was called in 'reducers'.

In development mode there is no problem at all.

The request **reducer** looks like

```js
export interface State extends EntityState<Request> {
  loading: boolean;
  error: any;
}
export const initialState = adapter.getInitialState({
  loading: false,
  error: null
});

export const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(RequestsActions.loadRequestsSuccess, (state, { requests }) => adapter.addAll(requests, {...state, loading: false})),
  on(RequestsActions.loadRequestsFailed, (state, { error }) => ({...state, error, loading: false})),
  on(RequestsActions.deleteRequestSuccess, (state, { id }) => adapter.removeOne(id, state))
);
```

and is composed in an **index.ts** file with other reducers

```
export const reducers = {
  requests: reducer
  // [...]
}
```

and the StoreModule is imported with the reducers map like this

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('requests', reducers),
    EffectsModule.forFeature(effects),
    // [...]
  ]
})
export class RequestsModule {}
```

Do you have any idea what's going on? Thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to wrap your reducer as function call like this:

```
const yourReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(RequestsActions.loadRequestsSuccess, (state, { requests }) => adapter.addAll(requests, {...state, loading: false})),
  on(RequestsActions.loadRequestsFailed, (state, { error }) => ({...state, error, loading: false})),
  on(RequestsActions.deleteRequestSuccess, (state, { id }) => adapter.removeOne(id, state))
);

export function reducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
  return yourReducer(state, action);
}
```

See the official doc -

https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers#creating-the-reducer-function

Comment: This applies to a host of other issues as well. Essentially, if you don't have an "export function" on your function, it won't be able to be run by the AOT compiler.