# How to use method CreateReducer in ActionReducerMap<State> object?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I want to create reducer by CreateReducer method, but I don't understand why it's not work.

I tried change State class, but I think it's not way to go.

```js
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  productsReducer: createReducer(initialState, on(ProductListActions.toggleImage), state => )
};
```

Argument of type '(state: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'On'.
  Type '(state: any) => any' is missing the following properties from type 'On': reducer, types

Comment: `state => `? You haven't provided the state change e.g `state => { ...state }`

Comment: Have a look at the docs at https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers or the official example application at https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/projects/example-app. Both provide clear examples of how to use the createReducer function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't use the brackets correctly. Remove the bracket after `toggleImage` and use it after the function. You can see the issue if you make more use of indentation. And you must return a state as well, because a reducer is a function that applies an action to a state and returns the new state afterwards.

```js
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  productsReducer: createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(ProductListActions.toggleImage, state => state) // <-- This ) is missing and removed after toggleImage
  )
};
```

In addition to that, you'll want to wrap it into another function, otherwise the AOT compiler will throw an error. See [docs](https://ngrx.io/api/store/createReducer) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56993101/error-building-angularngrx-8-for-production-when-using-createreducer-function).